# Unable to run Amazon Device Farm build in Jenkins using JenkinsCI Plugin

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, jenkins-plugins, testng-eclipse

I have successfully automated my test in ADF using Appium TestNG framework. I was trying to run the same build in Jenkins for continuous integration.
I have taken freestyle project in Jenkins.I am getting error. It is unable to find the pattern of .apk file. I am giving Application name the just apk file name e.g. android-debug.apk and in the test giving the" target/zip-with-dependencies.zip.But I am getting following error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWCSr.png)

Below is the picture of my configuration settings:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnkc5.jpg)

Please provide my solution of this issue.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found it useful so that others can benefit too :)

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device farm team. 
Good to hear that you are using the Jenkins plugin.

The plugin configuration takes your application and tests files assuming it is a part of your workspace.

**Way to approach this :**

1. Trigger a run without any tests or apps. This will create the workspace folder for a project if it is the first run.
2. Thereafter your tests and app go under the workspace which you can upload through the UI or place in the workspace folder on your Jenkins project.
3. The path in this case becomes **/yourapk.apk for your application and **/tests.zip for your tests.

Hope that unblocks you. If not let me know and I can help you further.